# Expression 'undefined' in attribute used with directive is non-assignable! in 1.4.9 but not in 1.4.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have updated angular library from 1.4.8 to 1.4.9. 
I got following error in 1.4.9 but works fine with 1.4.8

Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'data' used with directive 'mydir' is non-assignable!

In Doc, following use case is given.

```html
<!-- ERROR because attribute bind wasn't provided -->
<my-directive>
```

```html
<mydir></mydir>
```

```js
//Case 1
.directive('mydir', function(){
  return {
    scope:{
      data: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.localData = $scope.data || 'Sam';
    }
  };
});


//Case 2
.directive('mydir', function(){
  return {
    scope:{
      data: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.data = $scope.data || 'Sam';
    }
  };
});
```

**Case 1: works fine.**

**Case 2: gives error.**

Why?? As per doc, it should give error in both cases. Any suggestions??